# Postgres Returning HTML table tags grouped by column for resultset

Tags: html, sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to construct a function that generates the row and cell HTML tags which will be used in another application to build a basic HTML table. The row and cells need to be grouped/concatenated by the region id. This is the part I'm currently struggling with.

[image]

[image]

I've tried to put the following function together, but not really sure where to go to ensure that the output is grouped correctly by the region_id.

This is not something I would generally do SQL, but I'm working with some limited technologies.

```
create table reporting
(
    id integer,
    region_id integer,
    category text,
    item text,
    status text
);


insert into reporting values
   (1, 1, 'audio', 'speakers', 'delivered'),
   (2, 1, 'display', 'monitors', 'pending'),
   (3, 2, 'cables', 'hdmi', 'pre-order'),
   (4, 3, 'storage', 'sdd', 'cancelled'),
   (5, 3, 'software', 'business', 'delivered'),
   (6, 3, 'other', 'support', 'delivered');


create function html_out (query text)
returns  TABLE(region_id text, result text) language plpgsql as $$
declare
    rec record;
    header boolean := true;
begin
    for rec in
        execute format($q$
            select row_to_json(q) json_row
            from (%s) q
            $q$, query)
    loop
        return query select region_id,
            format ('<tr><td>%s</td></tr>', string_agg(value, '</td><td>'))
        from json_each_text(rec.json_row);
    end loop;
end $$;

select html_out('select region_id, category, item, status from reporting');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string aggregation. I think the logic you want is:

```
select
    region_id,
    '<tr><td>' 
    || string_agg(concat_ws('</td><td>', category, item, status), '</td></tr><tr><td>')
    || '</td></tr>' html
from reporting
group by region_id
order by 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=806ef121b9427bdaef45fcc78b8473d0)**

```
region_id | html                                                                                                                                                                     
--------: | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1 | <tr><td>audio</td><td>speakers</td><td>delivered</td></tr><tr><td>display</td><td>monitors</td><td>pending</td></tr>                                                         
        2 | <tr><td>cables</td><td>hdmi</td><td>pre-order</td></tr>                                                                                                                      
        3 | <tr><td>storage</td><td>sdd</td><td>cancelled</td></tr><tr><td>software</td><td>business</td><td>delivered</td></tr><tr><td>other</td><td>support</td><td>delivered</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is about consolidating repeating `region_id` with `rowspan=`, then you can get that in one go like this:

```
with consolidate as (
  select region_id, concat('<td rowspan="', count(*), '">') as rowspan 
    from reporting
   group by region_id
), trows as (
  select row_number() over (order by r.region_id, r.id) as rnum,
         concat(
           '<tr>',
           case 
             when lag(c.region_id) over w = c.region_id then ''
             else concat(c.rowspan, c.region_id, '</td>')
           end,
           '<td>', 
           array_to_string(array[r.category, r.item, r.status]::text[], '</td><td>', '</td>'),
           '</tr>'
         ) as html
    from consolidate c
    join reporting r on r.region_id = c.region_id
  window w as (partition by r.region_id order by r.id)
)
select array_to_string(array_agg(html order by rnum), ' 
')
  from trows;
-[ RECORD 1 ]---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
array_to_string | <tr><td rowspan="2">1</td><td>audio</td><td>speakers</td><td>delivered</tr> +
                | <tr><td>display</td><td>monitors</td><td>pending</tr>                       +
                | <tr><td rowspan="1">2</td><td>cables</td><td>hdmi</td><td>pre-order</tr>    +
                | <tr><td rowspan="3">3</td><td>storage</td><td>sdd</td><td>cancelled</tr>    +
                | <tr><td>software</td><td>business</td><td>delivered</tr>                    +
                | <tr><td>other</td><td>support</td><td>delivered</tr>
```

I put a newline in as the delimiter for that last `array_to_string()` just to get it to look nice.  A `' '` or `''` would probably be what you want.